# Disable/Enable 3G for ios app

Tags: ios, reachability

In my app I am doing live streaming in which user have a switch to on/off 3G. If user don't want to stream via 3G he could off 3G. My code is:

```
-(void)InternetCheck {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable)
{
    NSLog(@"No Internet");
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
    [self play];
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN)
{
    //3G
    if([[defaults valueForKey:@"3GPermission"] isEqualToString:@"3GAllowed"])
    {
        [self play];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No Internet");
    }
}

}
```

But if user turn off 3G and if there is no wifi, user could stream. How could i do this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to transfer data with neither a cellular connection nor a wifi connection available?!

Comment: If there is no wifi and user turned off 3G then I'll show an alert that please check you internet settings.